# .net drawing to bitmap using FillRectangle fails when Magenta

Tags: c#, winforms

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(16, 16);
var gBmp = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bmp );
Color col = Color.FromArgb(pdmsCol.Red, pdmsCol.Green, pdmsCol.Blue);
gBmp.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(col), new Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16));
mColourPopupContainer.Image = bmp;
```

Using the above code draws a rectangle into my control for given color. This works fine unless the color is Magenta in which case it seems to be drawn transparently. I guess this is something to do with bitmaps treating Magenta as transparent. How to I turn off this behaviour?

mColourPopupContainer is a UserControl (custom color picker).

Comment: It has something to do with mColourPopupContainer.  Whatever that may be, it is totally unclear from your question.

Comment: edit: mColourPopupContainer is a UserControl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is not very nice: Detect when **magenta** is used and change it to **not magenta**.

```
      var col = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
      if (r==255 && g==0 && b==255 ) col = Color.FromArgb(r-1, g, b); // Don't use Megenta as it can be treated as transparent
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the [`Form.TransparencyKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey.aspx) property to a color other than Magenta. This property:

> Gets or sets the color that will represent transparent areas of the form.

By default it's magenta, hence your issue. If you set it to some other color that shouldn't show up anywhere else on your form, the problem should go away.

Comment: OK but this code is inside a UserControl (custom color picker). Does this mean it needs to rely on the parent Form?

Comment: Yes. From MSDN: "If the color assigned to the `TransparencyKey` property is the same as any controls on the form, they also will be displayed transparently."

Comment: But I don't have access to the parent form, this is supposed to be a generic color picker control.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure what to do about that, you may need to change your implementation? Other than setting `TransparencyKey` in the parent form, I'm not sure of another way to do this (although that doesn't mean that another way doesn't exist).